# Python get object by id

Tags: python

I would like be able to restore an object from the python `id` function. So something like this:

```
a = "My random string"
internal_id = id(a)
b = get_object(internal_id)
assert b is a
```

Where I'm missing the `get_object` function

Answer (score 1):

```
import _ctypes

def get_object(obj_id):
    """ Inverse of id() function. But only works if the object is not garbage collected"""
    return _ctypes.PyObj_FromPtr(obj_id)

a = "My random string"
internal_id = id(a)
b = get_object(internal_id)
assert b is a
```

So but be warned you can really mess your python interpreter up if the object is delete. Causing a segmentation fault. Try running the snippet below and be sure you know how garbage collection works in Python.

```
import _ctypes
import random

def get_object(obj_id):
    """ Inverse of id() function. But only works if the object is not garbage collected"""
    return _ctypes.PyObj_FromPtr(obj_id)

def get_an_id():
    a = random.random()
    return id(a)

get_object(get_an_id())
```

[image]